# New password is only accepting old password not different password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, passwords

In rails 3.2.13 project, I am using devise plugin.
If I am going to change the password then I need to enter current_password for all 3 fields, if I try to enter different password for new_password & confirm_password fields then it will show an error message like "current password is invalid".

I have referred https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/bf5bcd52cb9edaefb002927434d7ede398e74bc5/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L46

In model,

```
def valid_password?(password)
 return false if encrypted_password.blank?
 bcrypt   = ::BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_password)
 password = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("#{password}#{self.class.pepper}", bcrypt.salt)
 Devise.secure_compare(password, encrypted_password)
end

def update_with_password(params, *options)
 current_password = params.delete(:current_password)

 if params[:password].blank?
   params.delete(:password)
   params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
 end

 result = if valid_password?(current_password)
   update_attributes(params, *options)
 else
   self.assign_attributes(params, *options)
   self.valid?
   self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
   false
 end
 result
end
```

In controller,

```
@user.update_with_password(params["user"])
```

Validation should work like,

- Current password & new password should be present
- If user enters wrong password in current_password field then it should check valid or not
- New password & confirm password should match

E.g.:

```
1st case: (shows invalid password message)

Current Password = "password"
New Password = "abcdefg"
Confirm Password = "abcdefg"

2nd case: (accepts successfully)

Current Password = "password"
New Password = "password"
Confirm Password = "password"
```

How can I change the password by entering different password instead of current(old) password?

Comment: why you used that messy code, devise gem automatically handle it... please follow the device gem... use this link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: I have referred same link but still I am getting this issue.

Comment: if you use the link than you don't need to write that messy code in model remove that

Comment: you can simply remove all that and have you generated the devise views? if not then generate and you will see the password view within that and you can just do changes if needed.

Comment: If I write this code in model then validation will work otherwise validation will not work.

Comment: can you post your complete user model code with the devise part, which database are your using.